# Minimum relay nodes in graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have the following problem. I would like to know if this reduces to some standard problem in Graph theory. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

I have a multi-cast network with 1 source (denoted in black in the figure http://s22.postimage.org/7a32mikc1/Graph.jpg) and $N$ destination nodes (red). The network also has $R$ relay nodes (green). The network has an associated edge set $E$ which describes the connections between all the nodes. The constraint for the network is that there should be at-least $k$-edge connectivity between source and each of the destinations. Can we find the minimum number of relays (and which relays) to meet this constraint. Note that in some cases $R$ relays may not be sufficient to meet the $k$-edge connectivity requirement and in other cases a subset of $R$ may be sufficient.

http://s22.postimage.org/7a32mikc1/Graph.jpg has an example network. From the figure, this network has 5 destination nodes and 14 relay nodes. But it is clear that even if we remove the three relay nodes circled in blue, the source still has 2-edge connectivity to each destination nodes. How to determine the relay nodes that are not necessary but still maintain the edge connectivity.

Comment: Is the answer k-1?  If the edges have capacity 1 then we need at least this many relays, and the configuration where the source is joined to all of the destinations, and each relay is joined to each destination and the source, has the property you describe.

Comment: I think I did not make one thing clear in the question. The network has an associated edge set E that describes the connections between source node, destination nodes and the relay nodes. The answer will depend on the edge set E. I'm trying to figure out a way to find the solution.